# TypeScript Error "Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, webpack, react-redux, typescript2.0

I'm trying to build a Redux middleware with TypeScript. This function

```
import { Middleware } from "redux"

function createMiddleware() {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      return next(action)
    }

    return next(action)
  }
}

export const middleware: Middleware = createMiddleware()
```

produces a TypeScript error:

```
Typescript error: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
```

Though the compiler does not complain when I remove the if-block.

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2016"],
    "baseUrl": "../src",
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Stacktrace from the browser console

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
    at resolveName (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24948:70)
    at getResolvedSymbol (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:32549:67)
    at checkIdentifier (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:33700:26)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38185:28)
    at checkExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38165:42)
    at checkNonNullExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35540:24)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35587:24)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35554:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38208:28)
    at checkExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38165:42)
    at checkNonNullExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35540:24)
    at resolveCallExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36556:28)
    at resolveSignature (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36786:28)
    at getResolvedSignature (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36809:26)
    at checkCallExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36836:29)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38213:28)
    at resolveName (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24948:70)
    at getResolvedSymbol (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:32549:67)
    at checkIdentifier (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:33700:26)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38185:28)
    at checkExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38165:42)
    at checkNonNullExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35540:24)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35587:24)
    at checkPropertyAccessExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35554:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38208:28)
    at checkExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38165:42)
    at checkNonNullExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35540:24)
    at resolveCallExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36556:28)
    at resolveSignature (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36786:28)
    at getResolvedSignature (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36809:26)
    at checkCallExpression (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36836:29)
    at checkExpressionWorker (..\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38213:28)
    at Object../src/store/middleware.ts (http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.js:69038:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.js:660:30)
```

Comment: Do you run your code in nodejs or in the browser? Afaik `commonjs` is the nodejs module system.

Comment: In the browser. I use Webpack 2.2.0-rc with awesome-typescript-loader 3.0.0-beta (same error with 2.1.4 and ts-loader). I cannot use setting `"module": "ES6"` because of a react-router bug.

Comment: Do you know if webpack and/or awesome-ts-loader actually support loading commonjs modules in the browser? Because 'exports' is an object that must be provided by the module loader, and according to the error you get that object is apparently amiss.

Comment: Yes, webpack supports commonjs: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/
The error seems to come from the TypeScript compiler

Comment: Added the stacktrace from the browser's console. You are right, it might have something to do with Webpack 2 from the looks of it.

Comment: I've switched to Webpack 1 and it works now. Thanks for your help, @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin, I figured out it was actually a Webpack 2 issue. Switching to Webpack 1 solved it for me.